# Error when passing a Python nested dictionary as a payload for POST call

Tags: python, dictionary, python-requests, nested-json

I need to use the below Python dictionary to be passed as a payload to REQUEST POST call

### Dictionary:

```
api_body_dict= {}
api_body_dict['loc1'] = {}
api_body_dict['loc1']['fName'] = var_fname1
api_body_dict['loc1']['source'] = var_source
api_body_dict['loc2'] = {}
api_body_dict['loc2']['fName'] = var_fname2
api_body_dict['loc2']['IDs'] = []
api_body_dict['loc2']['IDs'] = ID_list
api_body_dict['loc3'] = {}
api_body_dict['loc3']['fName'] = var_fname3
```

### When passed to the below POST call throws an error below:

```
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
response = requests.post('https://API',json=api_body_dict, verify=False, headers=headers)
```

### Error :

> {'errors': [{'code': '5000', 'title': 'Unhandled Exception', 'detail': 'Supressed', 'status': 500, 'severity': 'FATAL', 'source': 'IndexOutOfBoundsException : Index 1 out of bounds for length 1'}]}

When passing the below JSON directly then it is running fine.

```
json = {"loc1": {"fName": "XYZ", "source":"db"}, "loc2": {"fName": "PQR", "IDs":["123","789"]},"loc3": {"fName":"ABC"}}
```

It failed when tried passing payload as api_body_dict or `json.loads(json.dumps(api_body_dict))` or different combinations of this.

Any suggestions how to handle this error?

Comment: if you use json parameter, you don't have to specify 'application/json'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 500 code is a Internal server Error code so the payload is incorrect or the request is incorrect.

I believe your issue is the IDs key.

```
api_body_dict['loc2']['IDs'] = []
```

It should be "groupIDs":

```
api_body_dict['loc2']['groupIDs'] = []
```

you can also write the actual dictionary out with the variables embeded.

```
api_body_dict = {'loc1':{'fName':var_fname1, 'source':var_source}, 
                 'loc2':{'fName':var_fname2, 'groupIDs':ID_list}, 
                 'loc3':{'fName':var_fname3}}
```

Hope this helped.

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://API"

headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}

payload = {'loc1':{'fName':var_fname1, 'source':var_source}, 
           'loc2':{'fName':var_fname2, 'groupIDs':ID_list}, 
           'loc3':{'fName':var_fname3}}

response = requests.post(url=url, payload=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)

print(response)
```

Just added an example of the code I would run. just make sure that the method is correct so it is a post. also are there any required headers that are missing.

Comment: Thank you Issac
Sorry that was a typo error on my side, infact I have changed the query to IDs in the whole question. I still see the same error. Any suggestions please

Comment: Also I tried the way you have suggested and now its throwing the error
{'errors': [{'code': '4000', 'title': 'Unable to recognize request payload', 'detail': 'Suppressed', 'status': 400, 'severity': 'ERROR'}]}

Comment: can you share the code that you are using. a 400 status code is a result of a bad request

Comment: Thank you, it's all working fine now